# checking permissions inside stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, security, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure z that reads table A and writes to table B + C
it is imperative that the procedure does not halt while in between B and C (financial transaction like where you can't add to B without taking from C)

To avoid that scenario, and because the user running the procedure should not have any permissions on A, B or C, and because sometimes the server connection might go down I built the following:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [INV].[Z]
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @CanAcessAllTables int = 
        (SELECT IIF( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME in (A, B, C) ) = 3, 1, 0))
    IF      @CanAcessAllTables <> 1
        RAISERROR('Looks like we either can not connect to the server or you lack some aditional permissions', 16, 16)
    ELSE
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
                INSERT INTO [INV].[B] ( col1,  col2) VALUES (1, 2)
                INSERT INTO [INV].[C] ( col3,  col4) VALUES (1, 2)

            COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            SELECT 'Please report the following table for support:'
            SELECT
                ERROR_MESSAGE()   as ErrorMessage,
                ERROR_PROCEDURE() as ErrorProcedure,
                ERROR_LINE()      as ErrorLine,
                ERROR_STATE()     as ErrorState,
                ERROR_SEVERITY()  as ErrorSeverity,
                ERROR_NUMBER()    as ErrorNumber
        END CATCH
END
GO
```

My idea was that the sp would check if he (the sp) could access all 3 tables, instead it checked if the user running Z could access all 3 tables, naturally the user doesn't have permissions on all 3 and results in the 'Looks like we either can not connect to the server or you lack some aditional permissions' error
which is a bit ironical since by removing that raise error the sp would run.

**My problem then is, what should I use to make sure under any circumstance B and C run together or not at all (even if say someone renames table B to B_1 or revokes the sp's write permission on C)**

Comment: You're criss-crossing your concerns. AuthX can be handled by SQL Server directly if you use RBAC and require the same roles to access the sproc as the tables.

Comment: " 'Please report the following table for support:'" <-- Rather than prompting your users to report issues, why doesn't your sproc report issues itself? Also, using `INSERT INTO` without explicit column names is asking for trouble. **Always use explicit column names in `INSERT` statements**

Comment: Permissions on the tables used by the proc are not checked if the ownership chain is unbroken (as appears to be the case here).

Comment: Also, do your _human_ users really all have distinct SQL `LOGIN` and `USER` objects? That's a rare thing to happen thesedays...

Comment: @Dai, 
1) are you saying that if I remove that check on the tables I'll be fine?
2) thanks, the actual code actually has those column names but while simplifying i forgot them. thanks for pointing it out
3) Everything should be owned by dbo, yes
4) same Login and User, what leads you to believe otherwise?

Comment: Just re-throw the error or, alternatively, throw a generic but user-friendly one and log the actual error somewhere. And don't use SELECT to generate a resultset that contains a "friendly" message for the application to handle. Your application should be sufficiently intelligent to provide that directly (or not if a service or batch process is doing this). You push your own assumptions into your procedure logic.

Comment: I'm not expecting the code will ever get to that 'Please report the following table for support:' part because the actual code has about 20 "IF something THEN raise error" but it's still a very valid point, better create a table with those logs rather then push the trouble onto the user, specially since this will be run from flow and they likelly won't even see them

Answer (score 1):

**Error handling with `TRY\CATCH` in T-SQL is generally a waste of time,** unless you have a specific way of handling a certain error.

Using `SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()` will just destroy the full exception trace, as there may be more than one exception.

If you have a specific business error you want to raise (not just a permissions error that will be thrown anyway), use `THROW`

**The best way to do this is to use `SET XACT_ABORT ON;`** this will *guarantee* that any exception causes an immediate rollback, irrespective of whether the connection goes down, or there is a permissions issue.

To ensure guaranteed isolation and atomicity in your transaction, **you can use isolation level `SERIALIZABLE`,** at the expense of more and longer locks, and therefore a higher risk of locking and blocking.

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [INV].[Z]
AS

SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    IF(NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SomeTableToCheck WHERE Something = 1))
        THROW 50000, 'Some business error', 0;

    INSERT INTO [INV].[B] ( col1,  col2) VALUES (1, 2);
    INSERT INTO [INV].[C] ( col3,  col4) VALUES (1, 2);
COMMIT TRANSACTION

GO
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'm going to need to do some research on those functions