# "The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION" I keep getting this error when I try to execute my stored procedure,Help me

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, error-handling

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE Add_Edit_Courses_new
    @CourseCode          VARCHAR,
    ... other params ...
AS
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @ErrorCode INT =0, @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(25) = 'Action failed'

        IF @TaskType > 2
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR('Wrong action key',16,1)
            END
        ELSE 
            BEGIN TRANSACTION 
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @message VARCHAR(MAX)
                IF @TaskType = 1
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO Courses(...) VALUES(@CourseCode,...)
                    SET @message = 'Added Successfully'
                END
                ELSE IF @TaskType = 2
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE Courses SET CourseCode=@CourseCode,...;
                    SET @message = 'Modified Successfully'
                END                                                 
            END
            COMMIT TRANSACTION 
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
      SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, ...
    END CATCH
```

I wrote this stored procedure to insert and update and I used (1 & 2) to differentiate the task while using a try and catch, but every time I try to execute this stored procedure I keep getting that error, please can you help me with where I am wrong, I am just learning this principle for the first time.

Comment: Also re: `VARCHAR` with no length, please see [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: Don't bother with `TRY/CATCH` just use `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` at the top of the procedure, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68937413/checking-permissions-inside-stored-procedure/68938199#68938199

Answer (score 2):

Why is `BEGIN TRANSACTION` *before* `BEGIN`? I feel like `BEGIN TRANSACTION`/`COMMIT TRANSACTION` should be *inside* the `ELSE` conditional. With some noise removed:

```
    IF @TaskType > 2
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Wrong action key',16,1);
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN -- moved this here

        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        -- BEGIN -- removed this

          DECLARE @message varchar(max);

          IF @TaskType = 1
          BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Courses(...
            SET @message = 'Added Successfully';
          END

          IF @TaskType = 2 -- don't really need ELSE there
          BEGIN
            UPDATE Courses SET ...
            SET @message = 'Modified Successfully';
          END
                                                
        -- END -- removed this 
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        SELECT @message;
    END -- moved this here
```

In your catch you just blindly say:

```
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

This should be updated to:

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END
```

Note that if you have a conditional where multiple statements are not wrapped correctly in `BEGIN / END`, they won't execute like you think. Consider:

```
IF 1 = 0
  PRINT 'foo';
  PRINT 'bar';
```

You get `bar` output every time, regardless of the result of the conditional.

You had something similar:

```
IF 1 = 1
  -- do stuff
ELSE
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  BEGIN 
    -- do stuff
  END
  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

In that case, `-- do stuff` and the commit happened every time, even if the begin transaction did not, because that `BEGIN`/`END` wrapper (and anything that followed it) was not associated with the `ELSE`.

Perhaps a little dry and wordy if you're new to the topic, but Erland Sommarskog has a very comprehensive series on error handling here, might be worth a bookmark:

- https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html
- https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html
- https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part3.html

Comment: Do you ever see a reason for boiler-plate `TRY/CATCH/ROLLBACK/SELECT ERROR...`? I can't understand why people use it. We should just stick to `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` which guarantees a rollback anyway, and doesn't swallow exceptions

Comment: @Charlieface I prefer TRY/CATCH because some exceptions are more important than others, sometimes you have error conditions you can safely ignore, and sometimes you want to do other things instead of just abort (e.g. log the error or set some status somewhere).

Comment: But `SELECT ERROR...` is just evil. `THROW;`  would be better, as it rethrows the original exceptions (there may be more than one). And `XACT_ABORT` really should be on anyway

Comment: @Charlieface I wasn't endorsing or interfering with how this specific OP handled catch, that seems like a different discussion than how their conditional logic was flowing.

Answer (score 1):

Imo there are some major issues with this code.  First, if the intention is for the transaction to be atomic then `SET XACT_ABORT ON` should be specified.  Per the Docs `RAISERROR` does not honor `SET XACT_ABORT ON` so it could be converted to use `THROW`.  Second, in cases where the `ELSE` block in the code is hit then `COMMIT` will always be hit (regardless of what happens to the commitable state of the transaction).

Also, the code performs the `ROLLBACK` before the code:

```
 SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, ...
```

It's the `ROLLBACK` which clears the error messages and returns the state to normal.  To catch the error metadata `SELECT` it before the `ROLLBACK` happens.